# Sentry error caught TypeError: (0 , i.baggageHeaderToDynamicSamplingContext) is not a function

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering, sentry

I have a website built using nextjs and attached Sentry on it. It works on localhost, dev, and staging environment.

But somehow, it doesnt work on my main prod server. It shows error like this:

```
caught TypeError: (0 , i.baggageHeaderToDynamicSamplingContext) is not a function
    at Oe (client.js:93:34)
    at Ne.setupOnce (browsertracing.js:99:5)
    at integration.js:64:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at integration.js:60:16
    at ha.setupIntegrations (baseclient.js:217:28)
    at d.bindClient (hub.js:65:14)
    at sdk.js:32:7
    at re (sdk.js:110:3)
    at sdk.js:18:3
    at index.client.js:29:3
    at 37942 (sentry.client.config.js:12:1)
    at n (bootstrap:21:33)
    at e (_app-b4f4ecdac789e1ace475.js:74:2591185)
    at _app-b4f4ecdac789e1ace475.js:74:2591240
    at n.O (chunk loaded:25:12)
    at _app-b4f4ecdac789e1ace475.js:74:2591278
    at t (jsonp chunk loading:36:28)
```

I tried to remove node_modules and yarn install again, seems didnt work. Also I cannot replicate this on localhost/dev/stg.

For context, my app are using redirect. Example, my app is at https://myappexample.com/app , I redirect only the root url https://myappexample.com to another domain

Answer (score 0):

After posted an issue at their github, i fix this with:

1. Forcing the version, in my case 7.10 on package json with removing the '^' character.
2. My yarn.lock also messed up, so I replace with the new one.